# Android TableLayout - How to dynamically determine cells per row?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I need to create a TableLayout view that is can dynamically add columns based upon the size of screen.

For example, if I am on a phone, the maximum number of cells I can add per row is 5. However, if I am on a tablet, the maximum number of cells I can add per row is 10.

The *5* and *10* values are just *magic* numbers.

Ideally,  I would query the device to determine the size of screen, and adjust the number of columns based upon the size.

Here is my code for creating the TableLayout (it works fine):

```
 TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(mContext);
    tableLayout.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    TableRow row = new TableRow(mContext);
    row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    String[] separated = scheduleTimes.split(",");
    for (int s = 0; s < separated.length; s++) {

        // Five per row
        if ((s % itemsPerRow) == 0) {
            tableLayout.addView(row);

            row = new TableRow(mContext);
            row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }

        TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
        tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        tv.setTypeface(TypefaceSingleton.getRobotoRegular());
        tv.setTextSize(16);
        tv.setText(separated[s].trim());

        row.addView(tv);
    }

    tableLayout.addView(row);
```

Any thoughts on how I can determine the number of cells I can add per row (i.e., set `itemsPerRow`)?

Comment: Have you considered creating multiple static xml layout files for each size device?

Answer (score 0):

Get your display width in dp and then figure out how many dps you want per cell.  I think you've done the hard work already.

```
 DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
 float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;

 itemsPerRow = dpWidth / cellWidthDp;
```